# Linux server blocking certain client without rule defined. How should I investigate?

Tags: centos, block

One client is unable to access the CentOS server (can't ping or http).

Checking the rules in APF 9.7 (apf -l) and there seems no specific rule defined.
tracert shows each step and connection fine until the server is reached.

How can I resolve the problem and unblock the client? If there is any additional details required I will edit and add to the post, I am not sure what to check next.

EDIT

The client is assigned IP addresses in 2 ranges (both with the same ISP), 88.111.x.x and 79.69.x.x. The connection works when connected from 79.69.x.x.

Comment: Does `tcpdump` show any traffic for that client?

Comment: Are you seeing traffic from other clients on the same subnet as the problematic one?

Comment: @jgoldschrafe - no traffix from any on that subnet but that might be due to insufficient traffic.

Comment: @cjc - I am waiting to find out when they are on at the same time (we are in different timezones).

Comment: Did you check the route back from the server to the clients ? I'd bet that this is a local routing issue.

Comment: just to be sure: client is not from China or any other country filtering internet, right?

Comment: Client is from UK.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does this only affect a particular client?

If yes: could be their firewall
If no: Can you access said server from varying locations (home, office, vps @ come provider)?

I would advise checking if you can access the server from at least 3 locations (home, office vps) if this is the case then advise the client that the issue may be to do with their corporate firewall and to liase with the relevant support team ... given more information on my points above I can provide more insight :)

Comment: It is a fairly well used server with around 1-2k different clients per day. I can certainly access it from any location I have tried.

Comment: @Nick I'd be inclined to suggest the issue therefor is on the clients network, can they provide a traceroute for instance?

Comment: Hi, the traceroute shows correctly each step until the final step which gets no response.

Comment: @Nick what is the final device to give a response? the "edge" router into the server network or something else?

Comment: yes it is the edge router before the server.

Comment: @Nick can you run a packet capture / trace to show the flow of data in from the client and back out from the server to the client, proving the full round trip?